# Powershell to get AD user disabled in the past 6 months?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

How to get the AD user that was disabled in the past 6 months and also the time stamp when it was disabled in dd/MM/yyyy format as.CSV file?

Like using this Powershell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps ?

```
$paramhash=@{
UsersOnly = $True
AccountDisabled = $True
SearchBase = "OU=Employees,DC=globomantics,dc=local"
}

Search-ADAccount @paramHash |
Get-ADuser -Properties Description,Department,Title,LastLogonDate,WhenChanged | 
sort LastLogonDate | 
Select Name,Department,Title,Description,WhenChanged,LastLogonDate,DistinguishedName | 
out-gridview -title "Disabled Employees"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Out-GridView` to display the results, you need to save them to a file.  You can do that easily in the CSV format by using `Export-Csv` like this.

```
Export-Csv '.\DisabledEmployees.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

To be clear, just replace the `Out-GridView` line at the end of the pipeline with this line.

Comment: Thanks, Phil, that is what I need :-)