# Powershell to get the AD user that was disabled in the past 6 months confusion?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting, windows-scripting

I wanted to know which command or script that can be used or customized to search for the AD user account that was disabled in the past 6 months?

Script 1: Not sure how to customize this script below since it is quite complex.

```
# When an account is disabled, the userAccountControl attribute is set to 514. 
# Therefore, with Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata to find out when that attribute was the last set

$disabledUsers = Get-ADObject -Filter "ObjectClass -eq 'User' -and userAccountControl -eq '514'"

foreach ($disabledUser in $disabledUsers)
{
    Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata $disabledUser -Server localhost |
    Where-Object { $_.AttributeName -eq 'UserAccountControl' } | Select Object, LastOriginatingChangeTime |
    Where-Object { $_.LastOriginatingChangeTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-180) }
}
```

Script 2: I was able to use this script and getting all the column & filtering I need, however, it **does not show the AD account that was disabled in the past 6 months**?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$domainDN = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName

$excludeOUs = @(
    'OU=Shared Mailbox'
    'OU=Company Leaver'
) | ForEach-Object { $_ + ',' + $domainDN }

$Past = -180
$Days = (Get-Date).AddDays($Past)
$ResultPath = "C:\TEMP\ADLastLogonPast_$($Past)_Days.csv"
$properties = @('Name', 'mail', 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName', 'DisplayName', 'title', 'SamAccountName', 'CanonicalName', 'lastlogondate')
$filter = { (LastLogonDate -notlike '*' -or LastLogonDate -le $Days) -and (passwordLastSet -le $Days) -and (enabled -eq $True) -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false) -and (whenCreated -le $Days) }

Get-ADUser -properties $properties -Filter $filter -SearchBase $domainDN |
Select-Object DisplayName,
              Title,
              PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName,
              UserPrincipalName,
              LastLogonDate,
              @{ n = 'LastLogonDaysAgo'; e = { [int]((Get-Date) - $_.LastLogonDate).TotalDays } },
              @{ n = 'CN'; e = { Split-Path $_.CanonicalName -Parent } },
              @{ n = 'ParentContainer'; e = { $_.DistinguishedName -replace '^CN=.*?(?=CN|OU)' } } | Where-Object {
                  ($_.SamAccountName -notmatch '^(Calendar|Room|Account|Fax|Team|Office|Test|User|SM_|HealthMailbox|SVC)$') -and
                  ($excludeOUs -notcontains $_.ParentContainer)
              } |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $ResultPath
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `LastOriginatingChangeTime -gt $180DaysAgo`, not `-lt`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but somehow how to show the Name, CN and the date-time stamp in dd/MM/YYYY

Comment: If this is all about the formatting of the LastLogonDate, try: `@{Name = 'LastLogonDate'; Expression = {'{0:dd/MM/yyyy' -f $_.LastLogonDate}}`

Comment: Your second code block doesn't make sense. You say the filter is right, but it's looking for active accounts with a log on date after a given time. I thought you wanted accounts that were disabled within the past 6 months?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of your previous question: [Powershell to get AD user disabled in the past 6 months?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542122/powershell-to-get-ad-user-disabled-in-the-past-6-months)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to find accounts that were changed from enabled to disabled within the last 6 months, then your second script won't tell you that. You're simply finding accounts that are disabled and haven't been used in more than 6 months. Or at best, you can modify that to give you accounts that are disabled and last updated in the last 6 months. But some of those could have been disabled more than 6 months ago.

The first script will get you what you want, since using [`Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adreplicationattributemetadata) allows you find when a specific attribute was modified. So you can find out when the `userAccountControl` attribute was modified. But it does need some modification.

First, this:

```
# When an account is disabled, the userAccountControl attribute is set to 514.
```

This is not necessarily true. The [`userAccountControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-useraccountcontrol) attribute is a bit flag, meaning that every bit in the binary value is a flag that means something different (`1` = on, `0` = off). So the decimal value doesn't really have any relevance. To find out if an account is disabled, you want to look at the second bit. To do that, you use the [bitwise operator `-band`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-7#bitwise-operators).

That script is also pointing at `localhost`, which means you'd have to run it on a domain controller. But you can easily modify that to find a domain controller to point at.

I also added a condition in `Get-ADObject` to only find accounts that have been modified in the last 6 months, since if the account was disabled less than 6 months ago, that surely means it was modified less than 6 months ago. This lowers the number of accounts you have to call `Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata` on, lowering the amount of time this script will take to run. (Note the single quotes around the filter, that's important because of how PowerShell handles the date.)

```
$sixMonthsAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)

$disabledUsers = Get-ADObject -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "User" -and whenChanged -ge $sixMonthsAgo -and UserAccountControl -band 2'

$server = Get-ADDomainController

foreach ($disabledUser in $disabledUsers)
{
    Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata $disabledUser -Server $server -Properties UserAccountControl |
    Where-Object { $_.AttributeName -eq 'UserAccountControl' } | Select Object, LastOriginatingChangeTime |
    Where-Object { $_.LastOriginatingChangeTime -gt $sixMonthsAgo }
}
```

(For some reason, I found that `Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata` doesn't give me any data when I run this script in the PowerShell ISE, but it works just fine when I copy/paste into a normal PowerShell window. No idea why, but it's worth mentioning)

Technically this still may not find exactly when an account was disabled, since it's looking for *any* change in `userAccountControl`. It's possible that, for example, someone set the account to "don't expire password" after the account was disabled, which would also change the `userAccountControl` attribute, and this script would be looking at the date of the "don't expire password" change, not the disabled date. But in most cases, that kind of thing isn't going to happen.

Comment: I agree with the caveat in your last paragraph. It's worth repeating.

Comment: @Gabriel, the script throws error like:
Get-ADObject : Error parsing query: 'ObjectClass -eq 'User' -and whenChanged -ge 11/06/2019 13:30:28 -and UserAccountControl -band 2' Error Message: 
'Operator Not supported: ' at position: '47'.
At line:3 char:18

Comment: That's why I mentioned the importance of the single quotes around the filter :) You need to leave the quotes as I put them. The whole filter string should be in single quotes, and `"User"` in double quotes. If you change it to double quotes, PowerShell replaces the `$sixMonthsAgo` variable with the value of that variable, and then it thinks that the `/` in the date is a mathematical operator that it doesn't know what to do with. If you leave it as single quotes, PowerShell does not expand the variable, and the `Get-ADObject` cmdlet interprets the date variable (that's what you want).

Comment: More info here: [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)

Comment: That's great, many thanks Gabriel.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way:

```
# Midnight 180 days ago
$CutoffDate = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-180)

$UsersDisabledAfterCutoff = Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly |
    Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata -Server $DomainController -Properties UserAccountControl |
    Where-Object LastOriginatingChangeTime -ge $CutoffDate |
    Select-Object -Property Object, LastOriginatingChangeTime
```

The `Search-ADAccount` command makes it easy to find categories of accounts without all that futzing about with bitmasks. You will definitely want to take a look at [the documentation for future use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/search-adaccount?view=winserver2012-ps), because it handles a huge amount of the work for these sorts of things.

The `Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata` command lets you specify the properties you're looking for, resulting in less work for everyone. There is a `-Filter` parameter on this command, too, but I find that it's performance is sometimes awful.

Comment: Cool, thanks to you Sir Bacon :-)